# Javascript: My tooltip does not show its border

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

For reasons of learning, I want to implement a tooltip, which follows my cursor within a certain element in my page. For this exercise, I want to use plain Javascript to achieve this task. The canvas should show the current cursor position in a rectangle with a border. Could someone spot the error?

My page looks like this:

In the head I have the CSS declaration

```
<style>
  #tt  {
   border: 10px green;
   position: absolute;
   left: -100px; /* initially invisible */
   top: 0;
  }
</style>
```

In the HTML body, I have defined my tooltip like this:

```
<canvas id="tt" width="80" height="15"></canvas>
<br>
<div id="area">
  <!-- This is the area where I display my tooltip -->
</div>
```

Now to the JavaScript part:

I'm catching the "mousemove" event,

```
document.getElementById("area").addEventListener("mousemove",mouseMove,false);
```

have the following global definitions:

```
hcan=document.getElementById("tt");
hctx=hcan.getContext('2d');
```

and write the tooltip with this code:

```
var hx=e.clientX;
var hy=e.clientY;
hcan.style.left=hx+"px";
hcan.style.top=hy+"px";
hctx.clearRect(0,0,80,15);
hctx.fillStyle="red";
hctx.fillText(hx+'/'+hy,0,10);
```

I can see the tooltip text following my mouse cursor, but I can't see the border of the tooltip, which I have defined in my  declaration.

Could it be that the border is implicitly erased, when I call clearRect? But this should only clear the interior part of the canvas, not the border, which is just decoration - I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a border-style, otherwise you're defining `10px green none`

```
border: 10px solid green;
```

should do it.